# "Subscript out of range" error when referencing another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I can't get past the "subscript out of range" error arising from the code below. It throws the error when I first set the found variable.
The sub is for each sheet in the workbook, to search for an employee from a known column and identify the row, then use that row to sum a variable. Then it fills a cell in the active sheet with that total.
"col" is specified in the main sub.

```
nDate = Range("B3")
Dim startDate As Date
startDate = Range("B2")
Dim emp As String
emp = Range("B8")
Dim rw As String
n = 0

Do While True
    Range("B99") = nDate
    stringDate = Range("B99").Text

    Set found = Worksheets(stringDate).Range("D38:D144").Find(emp, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If found = emp Then
                rw = found.row
                n = Worksheets(stringDate).Range(col + rw)
                tot = tot + n
            End If

    If nDate = startDate Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    nDate = nDate - 1
Loop

Range(col + "3") = tot
```

I have similar Subs in my code that compiled just fine. The only difference is that in the sub above, I'm searching a range.
Below is the other sub that doesn't throw the error.

```
n = 0
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
startDate = Range("B2")
nDate = Range("B3")

Do While True
    Range("B99") = nDate
    stringDate = Range("B99").Text
    n = Worksheets(stringDate).Range(col + rw)
    tot = tot + n
    If nDate = startDate Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    nDate = nDate - 1
Loop

Range(col + "3") = tot
```

I know there are similar questions about the same error, but none deal with referencing external sheets.
Any suggestions on how to debug?

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of every module?  If not, your code will compile but may throw errors at run-time.

Comment: I don't have that. I get the error weather I compile the code or run it.

Comment: You set stringDate as a Date (which in Excel is just a number). Then when you call Worksheets(activeDate) you are trying to grab a worksheet by index with an index that is likely in the thousands (how dates are represented).  You need to ensure that stringDate is an actual string and that it matches a valid sheet name. So Dim stringDate as String. I am unsure how your sheets are named so you may need to reformat the stringDate variable appropriately.

Comment: I ran into that problem writing it originally. That's why set the "stringDate" variable as a string by getting the .text from a temporary cell for the current iteration of the date. That way, stringDate is now a string.

Comment: Would you mind telling me what a Debug.print statement of steingDate is right after you set it to B99’s value?

Comment: Joey, stringDate is "September 10, 2016" in the first iteration, then "######" in the second iteration. That only happens in the code in which I'm using the .find application. The stringDate variable iterates through the date range normally in the second sub in my post.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K I changed that.

Comment: BTW - How does the `If found = "" Then` ever evaluate to `True`?  That would only be `True` if `emp` (i.e. cell B8) was empty, which I assume it isn't.

Comment: In the subroutine that works, what is the value of `rw` while the loop is running?

Comment: Worksheets(stringDate) fails at some point because stringDate does not contain a worksheet name that exists in the active workbook, causing the subscript out of range error. As mentioned above, check this variable's values as the code executes.

Comment: My mistake, I copied from a scratch  sub. The code i'm running has: If found = emp Then

Comment: Variable rw is 54 after the first iteration. Which is expected.

Comment: Code in the question is updated now

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the beginning of the sub/function:

```
Dim targetWs As Excel.Worksheet
```

Then change the loop to:

```
Do While True
    Range("B99") = nDate
    stringDate = Range("B99").Text

    Set targetWs = Nothing
    Set found = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetWs = Worksheets(stringDate)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If targetWs Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet not found: " & stringDate
    Else
        Set found = targetWs.Range("D38:D144").Find(emp, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    End If

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        If found = emp Then
            rw = found.row
            n = targetWs.Range(col + rw)
            tot = tot + n
        End If
    End If

    If nDate = startDate Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    nDate = nDate - 1
Loop
```

If a message box shows up, you'll know you've hit a worksheet name that's not part of the Worksheets collection.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you each for your help. I was finally able to debug the sub.
Below is the code that runs correctly.
The subscript error was arising in the second iteration of the while loop when the variable stringDate was reformatted to a date rather than a string. I'm not sure why it happened in this sub, and did not in others with the same logic. The point of converting to a string was to move through sheets labelled by date in that format (eg October 25, 2016).
Either way, I fixed this by manually formatting the cell that holds the date of the current iteration.
I also changed up how "found" was identified after the .find was executed.

```
nDate = Range("B3")
Dim startDate As Date
startDate = Range("B2")
Dim emp As String
emp = Range("B8")
Dim rw As String
n = 0

Do While True
    Range("B99") = nDate
    Range("B99").NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@"
    stringDate = Range("B99").Text

    Set found = Worksheets(stringDate).Range("D12:D144").Find(emp, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            rw = found.Row
            n = Worksheets(stringDate).Range(col + rw)
            Else
                n = 0
        End If
            tot = tot + n

    If nDate = startDate Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    nDate = nDate - 1
Loop

Range(col + "3") = tot
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain that if you use `Option Explicit` in all your code modules you won't have these issues.  (It would force you to include the `Dim stringDate As String` declaration in your code, and then VBA wouldn't try to convert the value read into a `Variant/Date`.  And it would have also picked up the original error of `xlValue` instead of `xlValues`.)